# JQuery remove :last-child and .prepend

Tags: jquery, setinterval, prepend, css-selectors

i have next jq script:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#box div:last-child").fadeOut(200);
  $.post('_ajax.php',function(mr){
    $("#box").prepend(mr);
  });
}, 1000);
```

and next html:

```
<div id="box">
   <div>23:56:16<span>xxxx</span></div>
   <div>23:56:16<span>xxxx</span></div>
   <div>23:56:16<span>xxxx</span></div>
   <div>23:56:16<span>xxxx</span></div>
</div>
```

So, i need to remove last `<div>` from `#box` every second and `.prepend` new div which i get via ajax.
But this code works only on first second. I.e. after 1 second from page loading last `<div>` from `#box` removed, but next time just `.prepend` works.

Also, i need to know how i can remove several last child div's.

Comment: You know .post() is asynchronous right?

Comment: Yes, i know. Whats a problem with it?

Comment: Your code will remove the last div every second but there's no guarantee that the .post() request will complete in time.

Comment: @j08691 That's not so important to me. But... what you can reccomend me use to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem if you're fading out the element and not removing it. Every subsequent time it gets the element, it's fading out the already faded out element. Try this. Add the complete callback to the fade and remove the element from the DOM.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#box div:last-child").fadeOut(200, function() { $(this).remove(); });
  $.post('_ajax.php',function(mr){
    $("#box").prepend(mr);
  });
}, 1000);
```

Also, as j08691 pointed out in his comment, $.post is anynchronous, meaning the request may or may not complete itself in that 1 second. If it's slow, you'll be removing elements without appending any. You might consider fading out the element only when you're ready to append the new one like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
      $.post('_ajax.php',function(mr){
        $("#box div:last-child").fadeOut(200, function() { $(this).remove(); });
        $("#box").prepend(mr);
      });
    }, 1000);
```

If you're interested in removing a certain number of elements from the end of the box, you could do the following:

```
$("#box div").slice(-3).remove();
```

You can read about .slice here http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: Thank you! And how about several last div's?

Comment: What do you mean by several? There's only 1 last div. If you make this change, then every second whatever is the CURRENT last div will be removed.

Comment: Yes, i know. Its just one more question, if i need to remove 3 las divs, which function i need to use?

Comment: Updated answer to address that as well.